# Adding tooltip to an image

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Can't understand why my code isn't working, is there any way to display a tooltip on an image with extjs?

```
var img = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
        src : 'img/ampoule.png',
        width : 30
});

var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    target: img.getEl(),
    html: 'tooltip'
});
```

My image is in the dockedItems of a treepanel like that :

```
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'Search',
        /*****code code code everywhere*****/
        }
    ,
    img
   ]
}]
```

Comment: I've tried your code and everything works as expected https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6ta Can you add fiddle which show your problem?

Comment: @Akatum can't understand why it isn't working.. It's too much complicated to fiddle that because it's a treepanel with a lot  of data. Please look at my post again, I edit it. Do I have to declare my image in the layout even if it's declared in the dockeditems? I don't have any error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem can be that your image component is created but not rendered into page content when you are trying to add tooltip to image component's element.

Try to add tooltip after image component is rendered:

```
var img = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
        src: 'http://www.sencha.com/img/v2/logo.png',
        width: 300,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function(c) {
                Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                    target: c.getEl(),
                    html: 'tooltip'
                });
            }
        }
});
```

**Fiddle with example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6ta**

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience with extjs but I tend to delegate the tooltip problem to css.
As a rule of thumb when I can avoid unnecessary javascript I do it.

With pseudo element you can simply do this

```
.img_tooltip:hover:after {
     content: attr(alt);
}
```

For this you need you img markup (generated by extjs) to look like this

```
<img src="img/ampoule.png" alt="text of your tooltip" class="img_tooltip" />
```

Bonus, you can then very easily style your tooltip and even animate them.

I hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for you help to bypass my problem, it's working, but I'd like to know why I can't doing it with extjs.